# How do I read a file name to be used in my script?

Tags: bash, grep, ubuntu-14.04

I am trying to figure our how to make short bash script to read another file and to use it to spit out certain lines of text in a proper order

I want it to work like so. filename can be any file:

```
    myscript.bash < filename
```

What I have written in myscript.bash:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    ############################################################################
    #for greping info of scf files
    #
    #
    #
    ############################################################################
    read filename
    val1=eval grep string1 filename
    val2=eval grep string2 filename
    echo 'VAL1' $val1
    echo 'VAL2' $val2
```

Is 'read' appropriate in this case to use?  filename can be anything I just want myscript.bash to read it so I can grep information from a file

Comment: When you use redirection, you don't get the filename. The contents of the file are in the script's standard input.

Comment: Why are you using `eval`?

Answer (score 4):

If you want the filename, you need to make it an argument to the script, not use redirection:

```
myscript.bash filename
```

Inside the script, you use `$1`, `$2`, etc. to access the arguments, so it would be:

```
filename=$1
```

Then you do

```
val1=$(grep string1 "$filename")
val2=$(grep string2 "$filename")
echo 'VAL1' "$val1"
echo 'VAL2' "$val2"
```

Comment: @cdarke Not needed in assignment statements